# get value of reference of a nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-objects

I'm trying to write a query in to get IP address which is a reference of a nested table of a table that is reference of another nested table.

```
create type t_pc as object (
        Nserie number(20),
        adrIP VARCHAR(20),
        cpu VARCHAR(20)
    );

create type t_instatype as object(
    dateinst VARCHAR(20) ,
    refPC REF t_pc 
);

create type t_installations as table of t_instatype ;

create type t_logiciel as object (
    nomlogi VARCHAR(20) ,
    versionL VARCHAR(20) ,
    editeur VARCHAR(20),
    installationsR t_installations
);

create type t_refLogiciel as object (
    refLogiciel ref t_logiciel
);

create type t_reflogiciels as table of t_reflogiciel ;

create type t_adrType as object (
    rue VARCHAR(20) ,
    ville VARCHAR(20)
);

create type t_Depatement as object (
        codeDept number(20) ,
        nomDept varchar(20) ,
        budget varchar(20) ,
        refLogicielR t_reflogiciels ,
        AdrR t_adrType 
    );
```

Here are the tables:

```
create table Departement of t_Depatement 
    nested table refLogicielR store as rlogi ; 

create table Logiciel of t_logiciel 
    nested table installationsR store as insta ; 

create table PC of t_pc ;
```

Here the picture shows my tables with data

[image: "MyTables "]

My query should retrieve nomDept where the ADRIP is equals to = '192.168.2.'4 ;

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lean about [Performing DML Operations on Collections (at: Unnesting Queries with Multilevel Collections) on Oracle Objects docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#i463812):

> Unnesting queries can be also used with multilevel collections, both varrays and nested tables.

This is the query:

```
SELECT d.nomDept
FROM Departement d, 
     table( d.refLogicielR ) l, 
     table( l.refLogiciel.installationsR) i
WHERE i.refPC.adrIP = '192.168.2.4'
```

I guess, with this answer, I've unlocked next Oracle Objects freaky level.

Comment: thank you Man 
that is the exact solution I was Looking for